# Use Google Sheets API in PyScript

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, pyscript

*Including google-api-python-client in pyscript...*

Hello, everyone.
I was trying to use a code that allows me to retrieve data from a google Sheet using the [google-api-python-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/) library.
I tried therefore to import it using:

```
<py-env>
- google-api-python-client
</py-env>
```

But I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'`.

Full Traceback:

```
[pyexec] Python exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 460, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 306, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pyodide/source.py", line 1, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

I tried to search but couldn't find anything useful, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you reference `<py-env>`, I'm guessing you're using the alpha release of PyScript (understandable, a lot of online examples date from that time). I'd recommend using a more recent release, which includes newer versions of packages and the pyodide runtime and more verbose error messages. I would use:

```html
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.03.1/pyscript.js"></script>
```

Since version 2022.09.1, `<py-env>` was replaced by `<py-config>` and the syntax has shifted. In your case:

```html
<py-config>
    packages = ['google-api-python-client']
</py-config>
```

This shows an error message instructing to you install the `ssl` package as well, which Pyodide doesn't ship by default. You can do this by adding `'ssl'` to the list of packages to install in py-config.

Always recall that PyScript is a front-end library, and in order to access the Google API's, you code will need to [make use of an API key](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md#1-simple-api-access-api-keys), which will therefore be *visible to anyone who users your page*. For an internal project with non-public code, this is probably ok, but it would be quite a bad idea for a public-facing page.